# ffmpeg get FPS for each frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two questions

1 - Why my video FPS is set to 24, and while converting, show "fps=255, fps=249, fps=244..."? => https://prnt.sc/1t7xbj2
2 - How can I get "fps=x" for EACH frame? => https://prnt.sc/1t7xhi7

Thank you.

Comment: Add `-stats_period 0.0001`. Need v4.4 or newer.

Comment: What this cmd does?

Comment: Change the frequency of ffmpeg stats.

Comment: Ad. 1: FFmpeg, while converting, shows current conversion speed. In your example: 255 frames are being converted per second. That's regardless of your input video's FPS.
Ad. 2: I don't understand your question, but if you want to set the conversion speed to input video's FPS, then use "-re" option before "-i".